# html - hover effect: make div flow above another div

Tags: html, css

I want to create the following hover effect: on hover, one div (`.left`) is supposed to expand to full width and cover another div (`.right`).

This is what I have so far ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kubismus/tcm8nzu2/4/)):

**HTML**

```
  </div>

  <div class="right">
     <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/ddofbxz8d/image/upload/v1548087392/ka6fgbjakjeskramtkew.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 67%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  z-index: -1;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.container:hover .left {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**JS (JQuery)**

```
$(".container").css({'height':($("img").height()+'px')});
```

**Explanation/Requirements:**

The image has an aspect ratio of 1:1. The height of the `.container` div should be the height of the image, which in turn is supposed to have a width of 33% of the `.container` div.

**Problem**

Why is the image being pushed down, although its z-index is set to -1?

I tried multiple different approaches that I found online, but they are not working in my case. For example, I don't want to set the position of the `.right` div to `position: absolute` since I this would ignore the padding of the `.container` div.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consdier a negative margin to avoid pushing the image to the next line. You can also simplify your code using flexbox instead of float and you will no more need the JS code to set the height:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap; /*it will work even wrap enabled*/
}

.left {
  width: 67%;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.8);
  transition:1s;
}

.right {
  width: 33%;
  z-index:-1;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  display:block;
}

.container:hover .left {
  margin-right:-33%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
     <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/ddofbxz8d/image/upload/v1548087392/ka6fgbjakjeskramtkew.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```